# Переклад eye-tracking technology

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Речення:

> We use eye-tracking technology to understand...

В [українській вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3) вирішили не мучитися з перекладом, маємо *ай-трекінг*.

На [словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/treking-2) знайшов *відстеження*.

В [ґуґлі](https://www.google.com.ua/) знайшов декілька результатів по [*відстеження руху ока*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...49805.51291.0.51489.7.7.0.0.0.0.180.614.0j4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.iSBzFHEWCzA) і [*відстеження рухів ока*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...48338.48387.0.48692.2.2.0.0.0.0.202.202.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.MLYKWDBwh5Y), потім знайшов більше результатів по [*відстеження рухів очей*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&oq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...79822.80283.0.80429.4.4.0.0.0.0.142.270.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.6CRS6ye1jXQ).

Отже, чи можемо вважати переклад *eye-tracking* — *відстеження рухів очей* усталеним/прийнятним, чи я не доробив своєї роботи?

Comment: У російській Вікіпедії це називається «[окулография](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Окулография)». Слово _окулографія_ не є росіянізмом (це від лат. _oculus_ «око» і грецьк. _γράφω_ «пишу») і використовується в українських джерелах (наприклад, [1](//books.google.com/books?id=mBUmAQAAIAAJ&q=%22окулографія%22), [2](http://um.co.ua/9/9-17/9-172221.html)). Але наскільки має сенс використовувати це можливо-занадто-наукове слово в даному контексті (як я розумію, воно не дуже відоме за межами медицини, хоча іноді й [використовується](http://khustnews.in.ua/novini/6981-.html)) — не знаю.

Comment: @Sasha у цьому контексті взагалі немає сенсу. Це зовсім не науковий текст.

Answer (score 5):

Беремо [визначення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3) з вікіпедії і з'ясовуємо, що є технологія, процес і пристрій

> **Ай-трекінг** (технологія і процес) — процес визначення точки, на яку спрямовується погляд чи
>   руху ока відносно голови.
>
> **Ай-трекер** (пристрій) — це пристрій для визначення
>   позицій очей та їхнього руху

Для технології та процесу підходить дієслово [**стежити**](http://sum.in.ua/s/stezhyty)

> Пильно спостерігати за ким-, чим-небудь, не відриваючи очей, погляду.

Для пристрою підходить дієслово [**спостерігати**](http://sum.in.ua/s/sposterighaty), бо є назва об'єкту який виконує цю дію [**спостерігач**](http://sum.in.ua/s/sposterighach)

Контекст

- **Стеження за оком** - процес визначення точки, на яку спрямовується
  погляд чи руху ока відносно голови.
- Застосування **стеження за оком**  в маркетингу
- Технологія **стеження за оком** може ...
- ... стає використання **стеження за оком** для дослідження онлайн
  реклами.
- Одні з перших моделей **спостерігачів ока** вимагали фіксації голови
  респондента.
- Деякі виробники пристроїв для  **стеження за оком** пропонують ...
- Нижче наведено схему портативної лабораторії **стеження за оком** для
  проведення юзабіліті-тестування

Ну і переклад початкового речення

> Ми використовуємо технологію **стеження за оком** щоб зрозуміти ...

Comment: Поправте, будь ласка, форматування. Суть у тому, що текст між `backticks` екранні читалки читають по одній літері, як абревіатуру /бі-ей-сі-кей-ті-ай-сі-кей-ес/, і тому для позначення обговорюваних слів варто користуватися простим *італіком* між зірочок.